# Dynamically refer to Json value in Data Factory copy

Tags: json, azure-data-factory

I have ADF CopyRestToADLS activity which correctly saves json complex object to Data Lake storage. But I additionally need to pass one of the json values (myextravalue) to a stored procedure.  I tried referencing it in the stored procedure parameter as `@{activity('CopyRESTtoADLS').output.myextravalue` but I am getting error

The actions CopyRestToADLS refernced by 'inputs' in the action ExectuteStored procedure1 are not defined in the template

```
{
    "items": [1000 items],
    "count": 1000,
    "myextravalue": 15983444
}
```

I would like to try to dynamically reference this value because the CopyRestToADLS source REST dataset dynamically calls different REST endpoints so the structure of JSON object is different each time. But the myextravalue is always present in each JSON call.

How is it possible to refernce myextravalue and use it as a parameter?

Rich750

Comment: You could create another lookup active to get the json values from the same source and then transfer it to ExectuteStored procedure.

Comment: As I understand, `{ "items": [1000 items], "count": 1000, "myextravalue": 15983444 }` get from source input, am I right?

Comment: Hi @LeonYue I considered another lookup activity on REST data source to get the json value but I thought that this would generate another REST request. Tickets are arrays of objects, for example:
{
tickets: [
 {
 "url": "www.mysitea.com",
 "id": 4553355
 },
 {
 "url": "www.mysiteb.com",
 "id": 4662287
 }
]"count": 1000,
"myextravalue": 15983444 
}
I am saving all the json objects with every call

Comment: Yes, it will. I think it's necessary to achieve the request. Because we can not use the copy active input as the parameter to other  active

Comment: The lookup active output is  json data, we can get the myextravalue by the expression. Can I post it as the answer?

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create another lookup active on REST data source to get the json value. Then pass it to the Stored Procedure active.

Yes, it will create a new REST request, and it seams to be an easy way to achieve your purpose. Lookup active to get the content of the source and won't save it.

The another solution may be get the value from the copy active output file, after the copy active completed.

I'm glad you solved it by this way:

"I created a Data Flow to read from the folder where Copy Activity saves dynamically named output json filenames. After importing schema from sample file, I selected the myextravalue as the only mapping in the Sink Mapping section."

Comment: The Lookup function does not support REST type dataset. I think I need to do the Lookup on the data that was saved by the Copy Rest to Json activity, and retrieve the value from there.

Comment: I tried to prototype the Lookup function to read the JSON file already saved by the Copy activity but it cannot be handled by the Lookup function due to JSON file size - errorCode": "2107",
    "message": "The size 5465668 of lookup activity result exceeds the limitation 4194304",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "Lookup1",
    "details": []
}. So another solution is needed

Comment: what's the sink file name? The another solution may be get the value from the copy active output file, after the copy active completed.

Comment: Yes @Leon this is what worked. I created a Data Flow to read from the folder where Copy Activity saves dynamically named output json filenames. After importing schema from sample file, I selected the myextravalue as the only mapping in the Sink Mapping section. Thank you for your help

Comment: @Rich750 You're welcome, I'm glad you solved it. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.